# how to open CMD and write in another CMD

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to open CMD file and with in the new CMD windows
like this:
[image: screen capture]

How can I write something in the new cmd window?
I can use BAT or PowerShell.

```
start cmd.exe /c  D: & D:\Aither\Box\SysinternalsSuite\PsExec.exe  -d -i -s %windir%\system32\cmd.exe
```

Comment: Wouldn't adding another /c switch work?

Comment: no sry not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to *execute commands on startup* of the new console window (`-i`) that runs in the System account (`-s`):

```
psexec.exe -d -i -s cmd /k "echo hi & date /t"
```

The above runs `echo hi` and `date /t` when the new window opens.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
cmd.exe /c "echo hello"
```

Comment: thx for help but not work

Comment: The OP's command opens a _new console window_ (via `psexec`). Passing `cmd /c ...` as the command to execute there would execute the command _and close that window_ right after.